# Get text property from a Component

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPanel` called `panelCreatePuzzle` with 100 `JButton`'s.
I used

```
Component[] cells = panelCreatePuzzle.getComponents();
```

To get an array of all the buttons. Now I want to print the text of each button. I have no clue how to do this. I tried the following:

```
for (Component cell:cells){                   
    System.out.println(cell.toString());
}
```

Which does print something containing the text:
`javax.swing.JButton[,321,321,30x30(...),text=here is the text,defaultCapable=true]`
I can of course extract it from this string, but is there a more direct way that just gives me the text without anything else?

Comment: Do you know what method to call on the JButton to get its text (hint the method has a `get` in it as well as a `Text` in it)? Simply cast the component to JButton and call that method. Although best be sure that there are no non-button components in that list.

Comment: Note that your program structure is very brittle, and you shouldn't rely on the component structure of a GUI for your logic or program "model" code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are better ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but...

```
for (Component cell:cells){                   
    if (cell instanceof JButton) {
        JButton btn = (JButton)cell;
        String text = btn.getText();
    }
}
```

Basically, you need to determine if the component is actually a `JButton` or not and if it is, you can then safely cast it and work with it.

This is limited and a little brute force.  A better approach might be to supply a getter which return an array of the buttons which represent the cells (rather then looking at all the buttons, which might include things you don't want).

Probably the best solution though, is to use some kind of model, which represents the current state, which can then be used to displayed through the UI and manipulated in what ever form you want in a de-coupled manner.

This reaches into a large array of concepts, including "model-view-controller" and "observer pattern", concepts which you should take the time to investigate and learn

Comment: I think that he wants `String text =  ((JButton) cell).getText();` or something similar. Please see my comment to the question.

Comment: Figured it out from there ^^

Comment: I'm just sayin' that `setText(...)` isn't going to allow him to print the text. Now if this were your program or mine, we wouldn't be using something as risky as `panelCreatePuzzle.getComponents();` but rather would hold our buttons in a collection, or better still, use a MVC structure.

Comment: After playing with component a bit I already realised it wasn't suited for this situation. I just wanted to know how to do it as it might be helpful in the future. I'll go back and replace the whole `component` thing myself, ty for the help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yep - updated, thought they were trying to change the state and that the print statement was a debug process.  Also, yes, the best solution would be a MVC!

Comment: @RnRoger A "model-view-controller" concept, where the data/model is separated from the view/display

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I couldn't accept right  away (can't accept in X minutes) so I was just reading something on collections waiting for it to become available... On that note, a collection doesn't like when you add a JButton to it.